# Are Compound Triggers available in Oracle Database Express Edition 10g?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I want to code a Trigger to validate if a column have only a specific value, And if some user try to update or insert a row with the same value raise the trigger. But trigger doesn't compile fine. Do you have any idea? Do you know if Compound triggers are available in 10g?

NOTE: Only one "S" value is available for mon_oficial column. If some user try to insert a new record or update with a second "S" value trigger will fired.

Table:

[image]

Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_mon_oficial_trg
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE
ON monedas
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  v_check_moneda NUMBER(8);
BEFORE STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(:NEW.mon_oficial)
    INTO   v_check_moneda
    FROM   monedas
    WHERE  mon_oficial = 'S';

    IF
      v_check_moneda > 1 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010, 'Only one official money in table');
    END IF;
  END BEFORE STATEMENT;
END check_mon_oficial_trg;
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: This is the sort of question which can easily be answered [by reading the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28279/chapter1.htm#AREANO02318).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compound triggers were introduced in [11gR1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/whatsnew.htm#CEGEFAHF)

**Compound Triggers**

A compound trigger is a Database Manipulation Language (DML) trigger that can fire at more than one timing point.

The body of a compound trigger supports a common PL/SQL state that the code for all of its sections can access. The common state is established when the triggering statement starts and destroyed when the triggering statement completes, even when the triggering statement causes an error.

Before Release 11.1, application developers modeled the common state with an ancillary package. This approach was both cumbersome to program and subject to memory leak when the triggering statement caused an error and the after-statement trigger did not fire. Compound triggers make it easier to program an approach where you want the actions you implement for the various timing points to share common data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know How Can I create a DML trigger for avoid raise "mutant table" error in Oracle Database 10g?